# HERE Geocoding & Search API v7 - Search for specific food type doesn't work

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Searching for a specific food type doesn't work anymore (e.g. https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=xxx&at=51.500415,7.458788&limit=100&categories=101-000). (101-000 -> american)

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: It works with the older version https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse?at=52.521%2C13.3807&cat=101-000&cs=pds&apiKey={your-api-key}. For the newer version this is still in development

Comment: Has it been completed yet?